# Wrong encoding by response.write

Tags: c#, encoding, c#-4.0, response.write

I have a string in a web application
The string is like this :

```
`1234567890-=[]\ ;',./\~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?|
```

after encoding (by using Server.Encode() ) it show the following :

```
`1234567890-=[]\\ ;&#39;,./\\~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?|
```

which is correct

However , when I use `Response.Write(theSecondExample)` the result is like this :

```
`1234567890-=[]\ ;&#39;,./\~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?|
```

The backslashes are missing!

How can it be that the output is not what I expected? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  It looks like the double backslash is being interpreted as the escape character for the backslash.

Comment: What encoding? Backslash should not change using HTMLEncoding as it's valid HTML character.. post relevant code please.

Comment: How are you verifying the content? Using the debugger?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, I verified it using the debugger.

Comment: @Jan - the debugger escapes strings so '\' will show as '\\' in the debugger

Comment: @Andras. Doesn't that depends on the way you're viewing your result in the debugger? I believe you can choose text or HTML?

Comment: @Rob fair point will qualify my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no error - you're verifying the string in the debugger, which automatically escapes strings - e.g. `"Hello \ Goodbye"` will show in the debugger as `"Hello \\ Goodbye"`.

That said, the debugger behaves differently depending on how you view a string (and also whether it's C#/VB of course):

- Hover over a string (most common) you'll get the escaped version in a tooltip
- Watch window/Locals etc also display escaped version
- If you select the 'Text' visualiser you'll see the unescaped version - *which is what you should do to actually verify your string.*
- Html visualiser does exactly what it says on the tin :)

*Update*

Okay, so I've gone a bit further and fired up VS2010, please create a test project and follow it through.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  string a = @"`1234567890-=[]\ ;',./\~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:""<>?|";
  Console.WriteLine("Original:");
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
  string htmlEncoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(a);
  Console.WriteLine("Html Encoded:");
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", htmlEncoded);
}
```

(obviously I've used a verbatim string initially to avoid having to escape anything except the double quote).

Console output of the test is:

```
Original:
`1234567890-=[]\ ;',./\~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?|
Html Encoded:
`1234567890-=[]\ ;&#39;,./\~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?|
```

Equally if you breakpoint the end of the test and start mucking about with the visualisers:

Hover (`a`):

```
"`1234567890-=[]\\ ;',./\\~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?|"
```

i.e. it's C# escaped in the tooltip and surrounded by quotes.

Hover (`htmlEncoded`):

```
"`1234567890-=[]\\ ;&#39;,./\\~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?|"
```

.. again, it's html encoded **and** C# escaped with quotes

Text (`htmlEncoded`):

```
`1234567890-=[]\ ;&#39;,./\~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+{}|:&quot;&lt;&gt;?|
```

.. No c# escaping

Html (`htmlEncoded`):

```
`1234567890-=[]\ ;',./\~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?|
```

*In Times New Roman script of course :)*

Which I believe takes us back to the original string - which also shows that the scenario you're describing can't be the case - unless you have read an escaped string as being "correct", when in fact it's not.  Html doesn't require `\` to be escaped.

Comment: I used the text view of the debugger in VS2010 which gave the first result. The second result, which was wrong, was only shown in the web application

Comment: @Jan - sorry, but in my opinion the only cause of this problem is down to debugger visualisation - unless some other code in your project is modifying your string and physically double-escaping backslash characters. However, since ` \ ` characters do not need escaping in html, you would see ` \\ ` in the outpu page. Ergo the double-slash was never there in html encoded string except when you looked at it - and that can only happen if the visualiser you used was one of those that escapes the strings that it shows.

Comment: the html visualizer gave the expected result. However the result in the html did not. I guess it was something else. Maybe the JS code use to show the text.